# php check if previous array key value is the same as current array thats being checked

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
$results = array(
    array(value => 100, ID => 333, sec => 200),
    array(value => 200, ID => 333, sec => 300),
    array(value => 300, ID => 555, sec => 400),
    array(value => 400, ID => 555, sec => 500),
    array(value => 500, ID => 333, sec => 600)
);
```

to create a new array by combining similar IDs only if the previous ID is the same as the current arrays ID. Value is always the same as the first arrays value and sec is always the same as the last arrays value with similar IDs.

I don't know a way to check the previous array id value is the same as the current array thats being checked value. Hope thats clear enough

creating new array through

```
$display = array();
foreach($results as $value) {
     if(isset($display[$value[ID]])) { 
         $temp = $display[$value[ID]];
         $temp[sec] = $value[sec];
         $display[$value[ID]] = $value;
      } else {
         $display[$value[ID]] = $value;
      }
}

$display = array_values($display);
```

and thats creates $display to be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
         (
           [value] => 100
           [ID] => 333
           [sec] => 600
         )
    [1] => Array
         (
           [value] => 300
           [ID] => 555
           [sec] => 500
         )
)
```

but I want to get it to be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
         (
           [value] => 100
           [ID] => 333
           [sec] => 300
         )
    [1] => Array
         (
           [value] => 300
           [ID] => 555
           [sec] => 500
         )
    [2] => Array
         (
           [value] => 500
           [ID] => 333
           [sec] => 600
         )
)
```

Comment: Expected array will this [0] => Array
         (
           [value] => 100
           [ID] => 333
           [sec] => 500
         ) but you showing [0] => Array
         (
           [value] => 100
           [ID] => 333
           [sec] => 400
         )

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ']' on line `$temp = $display[$value[ID];`

Comment: Sorry, fixed those errors, and the expected output should be 300 where I had the 500

Comment: we don't your question because values are not equal and id, sec are equal?

Comment: AND Notice: Use of undefined constant ID - assumed 'ID' in

Comment: @qaakmnd, what about value

Comment: Is it right you want the value from the first occurance and the sec from the last occurance

Comment: On the first instance of id(333 in this case) the value will be the first instance of value with that id (333) and then the foreach goes through each array in result for more arrays with id (333) and the last one it finds will be where sec comes from. But I want it to only look at the arrays with the same ids that are next to each other and not seperated by another array with a different id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work

```
<?php

$results = array(
    array('value' => 100, 'ID' => 333, 'sec' => 200),
    array('value' => 200, 'ID' => 333, 'sec' => 300),
    array('value' => 300, 'ID' => 555, 'sec' => 400),
    array('value' => 400, 'ID' => 555, 'sec' => 500),
    array('value' => 500, 'ID' => 333, 'sec' => 600)
);

$display = array();
foreach($results as $id => $value) {

    if($id>0 AND $display[count($display)-1]['ID'] == $value['ID']) { 
        $display[count($display)-1]['sec'] = $value['sec'];     
    } else {
       $display[] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($display);
```

RESULTS

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => 100
            [ID] => 333
            [sec] => 300
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => 300
            [ID] => 555
            [sec] => 500
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [value] => 500
            [ID] => 333
            [sec] => 600
        )
)
```